Graphs of large girth, chromatic number, and many disjoint spanning trees.
A recent question asked for the existence of graphs of large girth with two disjoint spanning trees. The answer is affirmative, in fact, there are graphs with arbitrarily large girth and arbitrarily many disjoint spanning trees.
Erdős famously gave a probabilistic proof for the existence of graphs of large girth and large chromatic number. Later, explicit constructions were discovered. I was wondering if you can find graphs with all three properties: large girth, large chromatic number, and many disjoint spanning trees.

The random regular graph approach I gave as an answer to the previous question will also do this, but I assume you're looking for an explicit construction.

@MishaLavrov I prefer the explicit construction, but it is really immediate that the random approach gives large chromatic number? You could maybe write some short answer if you'd like.

We first reduce the problem of finding many disjoint spanning trees to having large connectivity. Recall that for a graph $G$, $\kappa(G)\leq \lambda(G)$, where the $\kappa(G)$ and $\lambda(G)$ is the vertex-connectivity and edge-connectivity of $G$, respectively. The following is a result of Tutte and Nash-Williams:

Every $2k$-edge-connected graph has $k$ edge-disjoint spanning trees.

A graph with huge chromatic number guarantees the existence of a subgraph with large chromatic number and high connectivity, which is a result of Alon,  Kleitman, Thomassen, Saks, and Seymour:

For every $k, m\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists a function $f(k,m)$ such that every graph of chromatic number $f(k,m)$ has a $k$-connected subgraph of chromatic number at least $m$.

The authors give the bounds $k+m-2\leq f(k+1,m)\leq 100k^3+m$. The upper bound was improved by Chudnovsky, Penev, Scott, and Trotignon to $\max\{2k^2 +k, 2k^2 +m -1\}$, and when $k=m$ this was recently improved to $f(k+1,k+1)\leq 7k+8$ by Girão and Narayanan. Since $\kappa(G)\leq \lambda(G)$, this result implies the subgraphs we obtain from the above are also $k$-edge-connected.
There are explicit constructions of graphs of arbitrarily large chromatic number and girth, in the following sense:

For every $g, m \in\mathbb{N}$ there exists a graph with girth at least $g$ and chromatic number at least $m$.

The first such construction is due to Lovász, but perhaps the easiest to understand is a construction  due to Alon, Kostochka, Reiniger, West, and Zhu (AKRWZ). Their argument takes a few pages.
We now combine these results. For any $g,k, m\in \mathbb{N}$ there exists a graph $G$ of girth $g$ and chromatic number $f(2k,m)$. Such $G$ has a subgraph $H$ that is $2k$-connected, of girth at least $g$, since girth is monotone under subgraphs. In particular, this implies that for any $k, g\in \mathbb{N}$ there exists a graph $H$ with $\lambda(H) \geq 2k$ and girth at least $g$. By Tutte and Nash-Williams, $H$ has $k$ disjoint spanning trees. Note: one can guarantee girth exactly $g$ by asking for a graph of girth at least $2g$ and then adding an edge to create a cycle of length $g$.
For the particular case of looking for two disjoint spanning trees, it suffices to consider the construction of AKRWZ of girth $g$ and chromatic number $f(3,1)\leq 21$. This will give a graph containing a subgraph of girth $g$ with two disjoint spanning trees.
Both theorems we use have constructive proofs, but calling the above an explicit construction would perhaps be an exaggeration for the following reason: the graphs due to AKRWZ are extremely large (Alon showed: the number of vertices grows like some version of the Ackermann function in $g$), so looking for our subgraph is likely hard. Nonetheless, there is no randomness involved.
